# Regex matching problem

Tags: regex

I don't know how to write such a regex. I will start with example.

My bad regex:

```
(\d*),?(\d*\.?\d*)-?(\d*\.?\d*),?([0-1]?),?([0-1]?),?([^\/]*)
```

Matches that are OK:

```
1,2-3,1,1,asdf
1,2-3,1,1
1,2-3,1
1,2-3
1,2
1
```

But unfortunately this will also be matched and I don't want it to be:

```
asdf
1,asdf
```

Ideally, I would like something like - match, if previous groups was matched.

I know that probably positive look behind should be used, but if I'm not wrong, it should be used right in front each group, except 1st and regex would be large and smelly after that. Um, and it would probably be variable length.

Is there any elegant way to do that?

**EDIT**

I want to match all lines given below *Matches that are OK*.

I would like to match `\d*` to first group. Then, if there was a match to `\d*` followed by `,`, I would like to match `(\d*\.?\d*)` to second group. After that, if there was a match in first group followed by `,` and match in second group followed by `-` I would like to match another `(\d*\.?\d*)`... etc. to the end of Regex.

Comment: Can you explain **what** you want it to match, not what you don't?

Comment: yes, what are you trying to accomplish?  That would help..

Comment: You're still not explaining it... Focus and post a clear question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not very clear in your question, but from the examples I think this is what you need:

```
^\d(,\d-\d(,\d(,\d(,[a-z]+)?)?)?)?$
```

[image]

It matches:

```
1,2-3,1,1,asdf
1,2-3,1,1
1,2-3,1
1,2-3
1,2
1
```

[Test link.](http://www.rubular.com/r/grB8hrtYtW)

Comment: Thank you for your code. This is almost exactly what I needed, but the most important thing is it helped me :) My regex looks now like this: `^((\d*)(,(\d*\.?\d*)-?(\d*\.?\d*)(,([0-1]?)(,([0-1]?)(,([^\/]+))?)?)?)?)?` Sorry for not being to clear.

Comment: Consider using `(?:your_regex)` if you want some groups to not be captured. http://www.regular-expressions.info/refadv.html

Comment: No, I need them all. I knew it will be trivial, but had no idea how to start it :/

Comment: Oh my, I thought I knew what you are talking about - `(?:...)`, but I didn't. Thank you very much.